# Как получить дату создания для каждого файла в директории

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. У меня есть папка, в которой находится много файлов большого размера, названия которых я не знаю. Я знаю только относительный путь к папке в которой они находятся. 
Мне нужно не загружая эти файлы в мою программу, проверить не превышает ли их возраст скажем, например, месяц и удалить если да.

Вот я нагуглил способ узнать дату создания файла по его пути

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        System.out.println("     creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
```

А как получить название всех путей к файлам? Ведь как я понял

```
File myFolder = new File("путь к папке");
    File[] files = myFolder.listFiles();
```

Грузит именно сами файлы в программу, что мне не нужно т.к. файлов много и они большого размера.

Comment: Можно так: String list[] = new File(".").list();

Comment: нет, не грузит, объект `File` (и аналог из нового api `Path`) - это просто абстракция, и содержит только путь. Он может, например, указывать на несуществующий файл. Раз уж вы используете новое api, то вместо `File.list()` пользуйтесь `Files.list( Path )` (или `Files.newDirectoryStream( Path )` если у вас java 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример готовой программы:

```
public class Dir {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(args[0]))) {
        for (Path file: stream) {
            if(!file.toFile().isDirectory() ) {
                System.out.println(file.getFileName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
    }
}
```

}

В качестве аргумента - имя директории